# Why did Captain Rex's phase 2 helmet use a phase 1 visor?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Captain Rex's phase 2 helmet (when he finally gets one) appears to use a phase 1 visor style, with it being thick at the nose and tapering towards the ears, while the standard phase 2 helmets start thinner at the nose and expand to make a larger blob around the eye.

Standard phase 1 helmet:

[image: Phase 1 white helmet]

Standard phase 2 helmet:

[image: phase 2 white helmet, visor is slightly narrower around the nose]

Rex's Phase 2 helmet:

[image: Rex in blue and white armor]

If you look closely around the nose part of his helmet, it almost looks like there's a line where a phase 1 face-plate was welded to a phase 2 helmet, but even if that's the case, it raises the question of why Rex would do and be allowed to do that. Why did he use such a strange helmet?

Comment: To distinguish him from the other nearly identical soldiers when the audience are looking at him with his hat on.

Comment: @Valorum I was more looking for the in-universe reasons, though out of universe answers are welcome too

Comment: In-universe: Even in the picture given (and seen in canon materials), we can see that the clones obviously have some leeway when it comes to the condition of their gear. They can apparently write, draw, and customize their stuff. Also - rank hath it's privileges

Comment: A somewhat in-universe answer would be that Rex was a high-ranking clone trooper and therefore had a bit of room when it came to keeping/modifying his own equipment. It might also be worth noting that Rex's modified helmet might have added benefits such as added visual and audio sensors, lighter weight or additional protection, but this is just speculation on my part **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

The in-universe answer for this is that Rex had his phase two armor customized. As said by another poster, it was shown that clones had leeway in their armor designs by the time phase 2 was introduced. This was due to the Jedi wanting to promote individuality in the ranks of the clone troopers, to in part increase morale.

The Kaminoans didn't quite understand humans needs initially, and in canon, Phase 1 armor was more durable but restricted movement and was uncomfortable to wear. Phase 2 fixed comfort issues, but actually offered less protection in the chest area, instead opting to provide protection from battlefield hazards and promoting better comfort.

Rex opted to keep two parts of the phase one armor that he liked better. The chest plate for durability, and the visor for visibility. In fact, the TCW episode "Water War" debuts phase 2 armor in the field, and Rex is seen in that episode on a republic ship, still in his phase 1 armor. This is not actually an animation error, as Rex's custom armor was not ready yet during the Mon Cala Campaign. He mentions in the Rebels episode  "The last battle" how his phase one chest plate still holds up, even after many years.

Sources: Wookieepedia, TCW "Water War" trivia gallery, *Star Wars Rebels* "The Last Battle"

Comment: Can you please quote directly from the sources and refer the sources used just when you used them.